# Exported Jar file from Eclipse not locating referenced files

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have written a Java program that utilizes referenced sound and image files that reside within their own folder under the Java project I have created in Eclipse.  When I run this program within Eclipse, everything works fine.  All resources are located.  What I try and Export this program from Eclipse as a Jar file, and execute it on the command line, it complains it cannot locate a referenced file.

Here is the command I've been using to run the program:

java -cp ./SeaWolfGame.jar Game.Screen  (Game is a package, and Screen contains the static main)

The referenced sound file it cannot locate is within the SoundDir.  SoundDir is at the top level of my project.  Do referenced files need to be in packages?

Here is the error I get back:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: SoundDir/sonar-beep.wav (No such file or directory)
>     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>     at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:120)
>     at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileReader.getAudioInputStream(WaveFileReader.java:185)
>     at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1162)
>     at Game.SoundPlayer.init(SoundPlayer.java:41)
>     at Game.SoundPlayer.(SoundPlayer.java:25)
>     at Game.Screen.main(Screen.java:1243)
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at Game.DrawingPanel.(Screen.java:101)
>     at Game.Screen.main(Screen.java:1348)

Now, I know the SoundDir is present in the SeaWolfGame.jar file by running tar -tvf on it.  I can see the directory and all of its contents.  Someone told me you need to generate a MANIFEST file.  I can see that the one present in the .jar file is empty.  It has no contents.  Is this an issue?

Would appreciate any help with this.
Thanks.

Comment: Entries in a jar are not files and you can't use file APIs to access them.

Comment: Look at using `Class.getResource` or `Class.getResourceAsStream`

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for answering my question.  If I just want to reference an already created file, which of these two would I want to use?

Comment: Both work, they just give different ways of accessing the data. Lots and lots of questions about this already on SO